# Drawing fractals in javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, fractals

I'm working on a 2d (for starters) fractal-project as a fun way to learn more about recursive funncitons. I'm looking for some function that outputs  coordinates for a line-based fractal, based on some conditional rules. Something like the H Tree.

Is there a name for such a function/algorithm? Are there any simple generic implementations available to look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just for fun:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("cnv").getContext("2d");
var f = Math.sqrt(2);

function hor(x, y, len) {
  if(len < 1) return;

  c.beginPath();
  c.moveTo(x - len/2, y);
  c.lineTo(x + len/2, y);
  c.stroke();

  setTimeout(function() {
    ver(x - len/2, y, len/f);
    ver(x + len/2, y, len/f);
  }, 500);
}

function ver(x, y, len) {
  if(len < 1) return;

  c.beginPath();
  c.moveTo(x, y - len/2);
  c.lineTo(x, y + len/2);
  c.stroke();

  setTimeout(function() {
    hor(x, y - len/2, len/f);
    hor(x, y + len/2, len/f);
  }, 500);
}

hor(300, 90, 150)
```

```html
<canvas id="cnv" width="600" height="180" />
```